# How to change directory through a script file

Tags: linux, shell

i want to execute some commands through terminal. I have on script for executing commands.Some commands are working but when trying to change directory its not changing. There is no error while executing that script.The script which i made is executable and is mention below:

```
make clean
make
cd /home/user
```

save this as script.sh and make it executable

Comment: do you have proper permissions to enter that directory?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Do you actually want to change the working dir in your shell by executing the script?

Comment: do you expect the working directory to be changed in the shell that executes the mentioned script? if yes: this is not how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current working directory is a process property. Each process has independent value for its working directory. Your script works correctly: it changes the current working directory of the shell process that executes it.

If you want your interactive shell to change working directory you have to instruct **it**. You can do it by "sourcing" your script into your interactive shell. "Sourcing" means reading the script and executing the commands by the shell that sources it. This is opposed to "executing" the script, where a separate shell process is started and executes the script contents.

You can source a script using `source` or `.` commands. Like this:

```
source script.sh
```

or this:

```
. script.sh
```